# Browser not responding due to long running script

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

I am trying to bind data to Ext.NET gridpanel through `AjaxProxy()`.Number of records binding is 3779. Getting `mysitename.com is not responding due to long running script`

Below is my code:

```
X.GridPanel()
                            .Cls("x-grid-custom twelve")
                            .ID("gridIRPAlerts")
                            .Scroll(ScrollMode.Both)
                            .AutoScroll(true)
                            .MaxHeight(240)
                            .EnableColumnHide(false)
                            .ColumnLines(true)
                            .Store(
                                    X.Store()
                                        .RemoteFilter(true)
                                        .Model(
                                                X.Model()
                                                    .Fields(
                                                            // Approx 15 ModelFields...
                                                        )
                                               )
                                        .Proxy(
                                                        Html.X().AjaxProxy()
                                                                .Url(Url.Action("GetAllIRPConfirmData", "CommonWidget")).Timeout(500000) //added timeout as record count is too big
                                                                .ActionMethods(actions =>
                                                                {
                                                                    actions.Read = HttpMethod.POST;
                                                                })
                                                                .Reader(Html.X().JsonReader().Root("data"))
                                                                .Listeners(l => l.Exception.Handler = "Error()")
                                                     )
                                  )
                                  .EmptyText("No IRP Alerts Available.")
                                  .ColumnModel(
                                        X.Column().DataIndex("Desc").ID("IRP_IDForHeader").Text("IRP").Flex(5),
                                        X.Column().DataIndex("Channel").Text("Channel").Flex(2),
                                        X.Column().DataIndex("PType").Text("My column").Flex(2),
                                        X.NumberColumn().DataIndex("Price").Text("New Price").Format("0.00").Flex(2).Align(Alignment.Right),
                                        X.DateColumn().DataIndex("Effective_Date").Text("Effective Date").Format(PRUtil.GetDateFormat()).Flex(3).Align(Alignment.Center)
                                  )
```

Getting data from DB in fraction of seconds, why it is taking time to bind data to grid ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any paging-toolbar on the gridpanel so I think you are trying to render all 3779 records into the grid.  Try adding a paging-toolbar and setting it for 100 per page.